# How to start the second div at the end of the first div.?

Tags: css, reactjs

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
    <div style={{ zIndex: 1050, backgroundColor: '#fafafb', height: '50px', position: 'fixed', width: '100%'}}>
    </div>
    <div style={{ position: 'relative' ,height: '250px', backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
    </div>
</div>
```

The second inner div height is only 200px the remaining 50px is inside the first inner div but i want to start the second div at the end of the first div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first div is positioned `fixed` , that means its out of the flow. Hence the second div pushed to top.

You could set the `top` of the second div by the height of the first:

```js
const Example = () => (
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
      <div style={{ zIndex: 1050, backgroundColor: '#fafafb', height: '50px', position: 'fixed', width: '100%'}}>
      </div>
      <div style={{ position: 'relative', top: '50px' ,height: '250px', backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
      </div>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```